# Project points using intrinsic and transformational matrices

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, transformation, emgucv, homography

Currently I am working on 3D image visualizing project using C# and emgucv.net. On that project following steps already done with 2 images of same scene(a little different in rotation and translation),

1. Feature detection(SURF), matching and calculate homography
2. calculate fundamental matrix
3. calculate essential matrix using above fundamental and camera intrinsic matrices
4. finally calculate the Rotational and translational matrices

Also I have obtain 4 possible answers for transformational matrix(3X4 [R|T]) using different combinations of R and T by changing its sign. Now I want to select the correct transformation matrix from those 4 answers. Before that I want to check either one of the answer is correct. So I have to re-project the points of second image using "Camera intrinsic matrix" and each one of "Transformation matrix". After that I can compare with resultant points with the second image points to confirm the result(translational matrix).

My question is, How to re-combine translational matrix(rotational[3X3] and translational[3X1] matrix ) and camera intrinsic matrix to project points into image points using emgucv.net?

OR any alternative method to confirm the transformational matrix that I obtain?

Thanks in advance for any help.